# Unexpected Git version: ''! You must install Git before installing Homebrew

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

Unexpected Git version: ''! You must install Git before installing Homebrew

I tried to install git with binary source and tried to install homebrew after that but got this error

Comment: Is `git` in your PATH?

Comment: Like are we talking about exporting path in .zshrc file?

Comment: Yes, it looks like Homebrew is not able to invoke `git`

Comment: What commands did you run to install git with binary source?

Comment: Basically, I installed git first, and after that I tried to installed home brewer.
But after that I got this error.

Comment: I think it might be happening due to I've got m2 chip in my macbook and that might be the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay! I've faced a similar issue and looks like we got this issue specifically in the m2 chip. So, what you can do is uninstall the git in your system and then try to install Homebrew again. I'm not sure what's the root cause but it did work for me.

Comment: experiencing same issue in my m2 chip

Answer (score 5):

Also happening in M2 Mac

1. Step 1 : delete git that's already installed
   `open /usr/local/bin/`
2. Step 2 : reinstall homebrew using

`/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 0):

found a solution from https://github.com/orgs/Homebrew/discussions/4341#discussioncomment-5376566

and it works

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
arch -x86_64 zsh
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Good luck!